# How do I click the "Yes" button

Tags: cypress

I need cypress to click the "Yes" button. I've tried just about everything.

[image]

I want to click the "Yes" button and get to the next screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cy.contains('button', 'Ano').should('be.visible').click();` should work.

Comment: May have to add the accent on the `A`.

Comment: Nice catch! `cy.contains('button', 'Áno').should('be.visible').click();`

Comment: Thank you very much it helped me. I should perhaps explain how you found it. I see you used contains() and should(). Could you explain to me why you used this particular command? well thank you

Comment: @Domo You can use cy.get('<uniqueSelector>') to get that particular button. But as the HTML doesn't have that, I opted to get element via unique text. And I used should just to make sure it's present in DOM

Comment: @TirathSojitra 
Could you teach me better? Or do you know of any training materials besides the Cypress documentation?

Comment: On Udemy you will find good tutorials, e.g. [Cypress: Web Automation Testing from Zero to Hero](https://www.udemy.com/course/cypress-web-automation-testing-from-zero-to-hero/).